# What is wrong with Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I am experiencing this VS environment glitch.

All these error message don't exist anymore, but Visual Studio keeps showing all of them even if there is just 1 error found. Double-clicking on any of them results in this **unexpected error** popup. Even if I scroll to 1 actual error message, double-clicking on it will open the file, but would not locate the error :((

**more...**

Yes, of course, several times, all latest updates are installed.

And it has nothing to do with code, it's some VS behavior bag.

This doesn't happen in Visual Studio 2010, even when I open the same solution.

If someone knows what I am talking about please advice.

[image]

One more screen - I purposely typed xxxxxxxxxxxx on Disclaimer.aspx, compiled, got an error. Removed xxxxxxxxxxx from  Disclaimer.aspx, compiled, no errors. Typed xxxxxxxxxxxxxx on f5.aspx, compiled and got errors including the one I had before (on Discaimer.aspx), that does not exist anymore, after clicking on it, I get that Unexpected Error popup. Basically it accumulates all previous errors that have ever happened before...
[image]

Comment: Looks like you need to reinstall.  Have you installed up the latest updates for VS2013?

Comment: "I have been experiencing this since forever." Well, since 2013, anyways.  What does your solution file look like? Are your directory paths correct? You are not posting anything anyone can help you with.

Comment: Oh, I have... I have reinstalled several times, installed all latest updates, Update 4, nothing helps :(

Comment: frashian, if directory path wasn't correct the project wouldn't load :) You don't need any additional information, if you know whats wrong or have experienced the same issue.

Comment: Are you using any extensions, such as resharper? try disabling them to see if they may be the cause.

Comment: Yes, the project would still load even if directory paths are incorrect.  VS would just complain when you try to edit those files (or, you'd get build errors).

Comment: Mark, Resharper is disabled, but even without it installed, I had same problem.

Comment: "What is wrong with Visual Studio 2013?" many things, my friend - many, many things.

Comment: frasnian, so true :)) but this one drives me nuts...

Comment: Can we see source file and build output?

Comment: I Already said it has nothing to do with source code.  Please read the post again. Thanks.

Comment: And as a sanity check, did you delete your `.suo`s and other temp files?

Comment: Can you try clearing your %temp% folder as much as possible?

Comment: I have the same problem. I just uninstall ReSharper and GhostDoc, remove *.suo file, and then restart vs2013. Thanks God, finally it works!

Answer (score 1):

Also sending this log file would help.

1. Open Visual studio 2013 from Start -> Run -> "devenv.exe /log"
2. Now reproduce the error.
3. Open the file %APPDATA%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\13.0\ActivityLog.xml and share the log contents.

Edit : removed the question about the details on the file that throws the error.

Comment: I already mentioned - it has nothing to do with code files, don't worry about this file, it's just something that was there when I captured the screenshot.There could be dozens of different files next second. It has nothing to do with code. Besides, that is exactly my question - you see "Visual Studio has encountered unexpected error" popup? Explain that :) And where is the value indicating location, in Project column?

Comment: Can you send the log file requested. That doesn't have anything to do with the code, but will explain more details about the error.

Comment: NP, How can I attach a file here ?

Answer (score 0):

According to MSDN:
To correct this error Close and then restart Visual Studio.

Source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ba78632y.aspx

How?

1. Open Task Manager with CTRL + SHIFT + ESC.
2. Look for Microsoft Visual Studio
3. End Task.

Answer (score -1):

Try deleting the SDF file that corresponds to your solution file.

Comment: I dont have any sdf file.

Comment: @SlavaLishnevsky The file is created by Visual Studio, it's not what you add manually. Check the solution directory, it should be there.

Comment: Note the .aspx filename extension.  An .sdf file is only generated by the C++ ide.

Comment: recursive search for "*.sdf" (any file with .sdf extension)- not found